# Access a parent class' property getter from the child class

Tags: python

I'm attempting to set up a test for a caching tool in which the cache is based on the function object and its arguments.  To do this test, I need to access the exact function being called in my property, and I can't figure out how to do this.

The caching code looks like this:

```
def cached(func):
    """
    Decorator to cache function calls
    """

    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(self, *args):
        # The cache lives in the instance so that it gets garbage collected
        if (func, args) not in self._cache:
            self._cache[(func, args)] = func(self, *args)
        return self._cache[(func, args)]

    return wrapper
```

and I have a cached property:

```
class SpatialMixin(object):
    @property
    @cached
    def longitude_extrema(self):
        return 25
```

The class looks something like this:

```
class MainClass(SomeOtherBaseClass,SpatialMixin):
    pass

MyObject = MainClass()
```

I can access `base_class.SpatialMixin.longitude_extrema.fget` directly, but this is a different object than `MyObject.longitude_extrema.fget` (which I'm using to indicate the getter of that property; you can't access it this way because `MyObject.longitude_extrema` is just the number 25).

So, how can I access the function underlying the `MyObject.longitude_extrema` property?

Comment: What makes you think `SpatialMixin.longitude_extrema.fget` is the wrong getter?

Comment: If you're trying to access the function the cache wrapper is wrapping, well, that's not the getter. The cache wrapper is the getter. You may want to make the wrapped function available as an attribute on the wrapper or something.

Comment: I've checked from the command line and the `id`s of the function in the cache key and `SpatialMixin.longitude_extrema.fget` are different.  But if the getter (i.e., the function `longitude_extrema`) is not the wrapped function... what is?

Comment: Like I already said, the `wrapper` is the getter.

Comment: Ah, that's more clear when formatted; I misunderstood the comment.  So the problem is that by wrapping `longitude_extrema`, I've made it completely inaccessible?

Comment: It's not *completely* inaccessible, especially on Python 3, but on Python 2, the process of accessing it is highly unwieldy. (On Python 3, `functools.wraps` adds a `__wrapped__` attribute to the wrapper, pointing to the wrapped function, though this behavior was bugged in some Python 3 versions.)

Comment: Thanks.  You've pointed me to the right solution.  If you want to turn these comments into an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to access the original `longitude_extrema` function, you're not finding it through `fget` because the original `longitude_extrema` function isn't the getter. The `wrapper` function created in the `cached` decorator is the getter.

On Python 3.4+, a wrapper decorated with `functools.wraps` has a `__wrapped__` attribute pointing to the function it wraps. You can use that to access the original `longitude_extrema`. (This attribute also exists on 3.2 and 3.3, but with slightly buggy behavior.)

On Python 2, `functools.wraps` doesn't set `__wrapped__`. While it's technically possible to get at the wrapped function anyway with direct closure manipulation, it's awkward, variable-name-dependent, and not a good option, especially since you control the decorator. You could just set `__wrapped__` yourself in the `cached` decorator.